# Calcular porcentagem em tempo real

Tags: javascript

Eu queria colocar 2 inputs na minha pagina, 1 o usuário irá colocar um numero( qualquer um ) e na caixa a frente apareça a divisão desse numero em 50%, em tempo real, como eu faria isso?

Comment: Poste o código que você já tentou. **Dicas:** Utilize `parseInt` ou `parseFloat` para converter o valor do *input* de *String* para *Number*; Utilize também o evento *input* no elemento *input* para detectar — em tempo real — as alterações.

Comment: Número inteiro ou com decimais?

Answer (score 0):

Então, para poder fazer isso, você teria de se basear em JavaScript também, pois HTML é apenas uma linguagem de marcação e não se pode/consegue fazer códigos vamos dizer, "lógicos" em sua linguagem.

Visto isso, basicamente o que você teria de fazer era pegar o número inserido no campo e dividir este número por um suposto "2" (sendo ele a metade de 1 número):

```js
function dividirNumero() 
{
    num1 = document.getElementById("dividir").value;
    document.getElementById("resultado").value = num1 / 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Número: <input type="text" onKeyUp="dividirNumero()" id="dividir" /> | Resultado: <input type="text" id="resultado"/>
```

Este é um conceito bem básico de como você pode fazer esse cálculo que você procura, pois todo número que você colocar, vai encontrar a metade dele. Existem códigos mais completos para se chegar a esse resultado, só que sendo eles mais complexos.

Indico a você dar uma lida [na documentação de Operadores Aritméticos](https://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/arithmetic_operators#Division) para que você tenha uma ampla exemplificação de como pode ser feito demasiadas operações com seu código! :)

Comment: Que faz a biblioteca na resposta? Algum usuário pode pensar que deveria usá-la.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo só se o usuário passar por cima de toda a explicação e não ler nada, pois antes e até depois eu falo que é apenas uma **INDICAÇÃO** para um maior entendimento sobre o assunto.

Comment: Eu disse que esse `3.3.1/jquery.min.js` está ai boiando. Sem utilização de fato.